# Pascal's triangle with memoization

Tags: python, recursion

#### Problem:

> Pascal’s triangle is a useful recursive definition that tells us the
>   coefficients in the expansion of the polynomial (x + a)^n. Each
>   element in the triangle has a coordinate, given by the row it is on
>   and its position in the row (which you could call its column). Every
>   number in Pascal’s triangle is defined as the sum of the item above it
>   and the item that is directly to the upper left of it. If there is a
>   position that does not have an entry, we treat it as if we had a 0
>   there. Below are the first few rows of the triangle:
>
> ```
> Item:   0  1  2  3  4  5
>
> Row 0:  1
>
> Row 1:  1  1
>
> Row 2:  1  2  1
>
> Row 3:  1  3  3  1
>
> Row 4:  1  4  6  4  1
>
> Row 5:  1  5 10 10  5  1
>
> ...
> ```
>
> Define the procedure `pascal(row, column)` which takes a `row` and a
>   `column`, and finds the value at that position in the triangle. Don’t
>   use the closed-form solution, if you know it.

#### Solution:

```
def pascal_with_memoization(row, column):
    """
    >>> pascal_with_memoization(3, 2)
    3
    >>> pascal_with_memoization(3, 3)
    1
    >>> pascal_with_memoization(5,4)
    5
    """
    cache = {}
    for row_indx in range(0, row + 1):
        cache.setdefault(row_indx, []).insert(0, 1)
    for col_indx in range(1, column + 1):
        cache.setdefault(0, []).insert(col_indx, 0) 
    def pascal(row, column):
        if column == 0:
            return cache[row][column]
        elif row  == 0:
            return  cache[row][column]
        else:
            value_1 = 0
            value_2 = 0
            lst = cache[row-1]
            if len(lst) > column: 
                value_1 = cache[row-1][column]
                value_2 = cache[row-1][column-1]
            elif len(lst) > column - 1:
                value_1 = pascal(row-1, column)
                value_2 = cache[row-1][column-1]  
                cache.setdefault(row-1, []).insert(column, value_1)
            else:
                value_1 = pascal(row-1, column)
                value_2 = pascal(row-1, column-1)
            return value_1 + value_2
    return pascal(row, column)
```

Can we improve the memoized code?

Comment: I did not see above code asking for `nonlocal` declaration of `cache`. I did not see any error like `reference before assignment`

Comment: You're not actually implementing memoization because the cache is local the the function scope. Try declaring it outside the function instead.

Comment: @jacwah  We require `cache` to run this tree recursion efficiently. Other than this, there is no other purpose of this `cache`. so why global `cache`? I am using memoization to increase the performance of this tree recursion. Now, why memoization definition demands the `cache` to be global? am not sure.

Comment: Because every time the function is called, a new version of `cache` is created. It has to be shared by all calls to the function to be useful.

Comment: Instead of making it global, you could make it an attribute of the function itself - `pascal_with_memoization.cache`.

Answer (score 10):

The canonical way to memoize Python code is with a decorator, for example:

```
from functools import wraps

def memoize(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in wrapper.cache:
            wrapper.cache[args] = func(*args)
        return wrapper.cache[args]
    wrapper.cache = {}
    return wrapper
```

*([`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) is to handle the name of and any docstrings on the memoized function)*. Within the function itself, you don't need to refer to the `cache` at all; you simply make a recursive call and let the decorator handle the caching. This makes your code much easier to read and write, because the only difference is:

```
@memoize  # a single line
def pascal(row, column):
    if row < 0 or column < 0 or column > row:
        raise ValueError
    if column == 0 or column == row:
        return 1
    return pascal(row-1, column) + pascal(row-1, column-1)
```

You can see the cache fill up as you use the function:

```
>>> pascal.cache
{}
>>> pascal(4, 3)
4
>>> pascal.cache
{(3, 2): 3, (3, 3): 1, (2, 1): 2, (4, 3): 4, (2, 2): 1, (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can avoid generating some of the numbers of the triangle.

From looking at the triangle, every single value in the first column, ie if column == 0, has to be a 1, if asked to generate it we can just return 1. Similarly we can do the same if the column equals the row.

```
if(column == 0 or column == row):
    return 1
```

---

The next column is just counting upwards, so if column is 1 or if it is row - 1 (both conditions presuming row > 0), we can just return row.

```
if(row > 0):
    if(column == 1 or column == row - 1):
        return row
```

---

Lastly, and most importantly, since the triangle is symmetric, only half of it needs to be generated in the first place.

The mid point of the row is given by row/2 + 1.

```
0 1 2 ... x ... mid-1 mid mid+1 ... col ... row-1 row
```

We want the co-ordinate x such that (x + column)/2 = mid, ie mid is the mid point of both values

```
x = 2*mid - column
x = 2*(row/2 + 1) - column  
x = 2*row/2 + 2 - column
x = row + 2 - column
```

So the code is something like

```
if(column > row/2 + 1):
    return cache[row][row + 2 - column] //or pascal(row, row + 2 - column) if that has a check to see if a number is already stored
```

Important Note: this presumes you are generating each row from left to right, so the value will already produced.

I haven't tested the performance of such code, but since it doesn't have to recalculate half the triangle, I presume it would be faster